# Converting GraphQL bigint to Android (Java) Integer during build phase

Tags: java, android, apollo

I am working on an Android (java) application that uses the Apollo framework to use a GraphQL database. We recently changed some `Integers` to `BigIntegers` in the database, but now the Android project is building those values as type `Object` once they enter java-land.

How do I get Apollo to build `bigints` as `Integer` so that I can work with these fields?

Comment: You likely changed them to `BigIntegers` in the database because you needed the larger value-range, which means that Java's `Integer` is not enough either, so your Java code should use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), otherwise you'll just get numeric overflow in the Java code. --- The "type `Object`" you're getting are likely `BigInteger` objects.

Comment: Okay, so then how do I get Apollo to generate those fields as BigInteger instead of Object?